# Unable to deploy Xamarin.iOS app targeting iOS 7.1 from Visual Studio

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin, building

I have few error when i building iOS APP with Visual Studio installed on my PC.

Everyone is in the Properties APP:

*SDK version is empty and i can't choose anything.
*Deployment target is empty and i see error: Unable to retrive iOS SDK information form XamarinMac Agent server.
*in Bundle: Failed to obtain Profile Information from the build server.

I try to build application on iPhone 4 IOS 7.1 and building process stoping one :Launching 'App' on 'iPhome'... and anything happening.

Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: Could you make sure you have iOS 7.1 SDK installed on your Mac? Also make sure that Xamarin tools are updated on both Visual Studio and Mac

Comment: I have XCODE 7.3 version on my Mac. Is this version include iOS 7.1 SDK? I'am installing xamarin yesterday on both, so i think it is up to date.

Comment: It does not by default. Go to preferences>downloads and then download iOS 7.1 simulator/SDK. If it's not available you may want to downgrade to older versions

Comment: Ok, but I don't see any sdk in dropdown. It is normal?

Comment: Are you successfully connecting to the build host with *full support*?

Comment: It looks like, XCode 7.x does not support iOS 7.1. You need to try the workaround suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31056634/85606 or use the older version Xamarin tools and XCode 6

Comment: Yes, i will connecting with full support (little green icon :)).

Comment: Ok but why i can't see any other SDK?? My troubles is similar like this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090920/xamarin-studio-preferences-projects-sdk-locations-apple-xamarin-ios-sd